# How can I put a route like "/items?Search="?

Tags: reactjs

I have been assigned a task where I must put a route with the following url: `/items?search=` to load `SearchBarScreen` component.

I have this code and I am `using react-router-dom` package:

```
    export const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/items?search=" component={SearchBarScreen} />
            <Route exact path="/product/:id" component={ProductDetailScreen} />
            <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Route component={NotFoundScreen} />
        </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
```

I can't load my `SearchBarScreen` component with the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/items?search=XDDD
```

the route `HomeScreen` `(/)` is loaded in this case :(

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your goal? To be able to access `XDDD` value inside `SearchBarScreen`?

Comment: @codemonkey my goal is to access the component `SearchBarScreen` using `http://localhost:3000/items?search=` in the browser (see the config of my router)

Answer (score 2):

You should feed the URI without the query string to the Route component. So if you want to render your `SearchBarScreen` at this URL `http://localhost:3000/items?search=`, you should do this:

```
<Route exact path="/items" component={SearchBarScreen} />
```

And then access the query string inside `SearchBarScreen` like so:

```
const SearchBarScreen = ({ match, location }) => {
  console.log(location.search);
  return <div>Search results</div>;
};
```

Another way is to drop the `exact` prop.

My recommended solution is the former. Here is a Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-http-lkqfj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks for your help, I was checking your code and I have a problem ... with this url  `https://lkqfj.csb.app/ite*ms?search=somequery`, (look `ite*ms`)  it should show `<Route>
            <div>Not found</div>
          </Route>` but `HomeScreen` is loaded..

Comment: @yavg That's because `<Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />` didn't have the exact prop. It's there now, so if you try now, it will do as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The `exact` param is used when you have multiple paths that have similar names:
for exmplae in your code  when you go to `//localhost:3000/items?search=XDDD`  the router will go through all of our defined routes and return the FIRST match it finds.And this is the first thing it finds `//localhost:3000/` And executes the `HomeScreen` component.
The `exact` param disables the partial matching for a route and makes sure that it only returns the route if the path is an EXACT match to the current url.
So in this case,you should add exact to  `/` route:

```
 <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/items?search=" component={SearchBarScreen} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductDetailScreen} />
            <Route  exact  path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Route component={NotFoundScreen} />
        </Switch>
        </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

You can use this custom hook

useLocation hook is imported from react-router-dom

```
 useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}
```

Then in component

```
const query = useQuery();
```

[Docs Query param example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)